# Personal page - name with foreign accent

Tags: seo, html, meta-tags, name

I am writing HTML code for my personal webpage.
I used GitHub page to host it. I am French and my firstname Céline contains accents. Assume my surname is Foo.

There is two kind of request from the people who want to see my page:

1. either they will look for my firstname without accent that is "Celine Foo homepage"
2. or they will type "Céline Foo page personnelle"

How can I handle these requests so that they point on my personal page?

Here is my sample of index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <font color="black" face="Lucida console" size=+1>
<head>
  <meta name="author" content="Ceacuteline Foo">
  <meta name="description" content="Celine Foo homepage" />
  <meta name="Keywords" content="C&eacuteline Foo">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <title>Homepage of Celine Foo</title>
</head>
```

I know that the title of my HTML page and the meta tags are important, I would like some enlightments on these points to solve my problem.

Comment: Tip: The meta[name="keywords"] tag is not used anymore. [source](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)

Comment: Tip 2: The font tag is deprecated in html5. You should use css for styling links.

Comment: Set the coding to UTF-8 and lang, so you don't use entities and write the propper accents.

Answer (score 3):

The right way to handle this situation is to have two index.html files, one for each language.

Then you will need to fill the **title** html tag and **meta description** tag in English and in the other page the French version.

After that you should specify that each page has the same content but in a different language using the special **hreflang** in both pages something like:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mywebsite.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://mywebsitr.com/fr" />
```

Then when people google *Céline*, Google will decide the best page version to show up regarding user context, its language or google version used, etc.

Comment: Thanks marcanuy.
So I host website in order to have two index.html ?
I have two folders, one for my english page and the other for the french page ?

Comment: You can choose to have your language versions in subdirectories like: (english version) mysite.com/index.html, (french version) mysite.com/fr/index.html read more at https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1 and https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this answer, but it's really helpful and will work like charm.

Comment: in fact one discrepancy is since my two files index.html have the same body (but not header), it is difficult to maintiain them: if I modify the body of one file, I have to change the body of the other file the same way ...

I didn't find simple method to include html file with no script, so it's not perfect but it's works

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991754/include-html-simplest-way

Comment: @Smilia If you don't specify that in the question I can't know it beforehand, I don't think it is a valid reason to down vote it. In this case you can use a template system with template inheritance, that week make it easy to include chunks of html, as you are already using githubpages then you can use Jekyll as it is the blog engine supported by default and it already uses a template engine. Have a look at [includes](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes)

Comment: thanks marcanuy, I will have a look. I also think it doesn't deserve a vote down (it was not me)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the correct version in your page and the search engines (ie. Google) will figure it out.

Part of the "search" algorithm is to understand word alternatives and relationships and to return what the user excepts to see. You can see this in Google search. For example, search for `Celine` (no accent) and most of the results are for `Céline` (even when using a quoted "verbatim" search; which is a bit surprising?). In fact, just using the browser's in-page search facility "combines" these two words: search for `Celine` and both "Céline" and "Celine" are highlighted.

Aside: the `keywords` meta tag does not help with indexing in Google.

Comment: Ok thanks

what if my firstname is Jérémy (French). It also exists in english ; Jeremy.

So if people look for 'Jeremy  Foo' (no verbatim) in Google, they will have the contents with the Jeremy and not my homepage.
How to deal with this problem when the firstname is both french and english and with accents in French ?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Maybe the users locale takes precedence in this case? "Jeremy" is a very common English/UK name, so for someone searching from the UK on `google.co.uk` it would make sense for "Jeremy" to be the predominant result in the SERPs. However, if someone is searching from France on `google.co.uk`, the results are probably going to be very different.

Comment: ok I see, in that case, is there a easy to take into account people looking for "Jeremy" from  google.co.uk from UK and people looking for "Jérémy" from google.fr.
Or am I force to make a choice ?